# Confusing using 'shuf' to delete an array element

Tags: arrays, bash, shuffle

I have been teaching myself bash for months now and I'm confused about the behavior of removing elements in a variable.

Here is a test:

```
array=( "one" "two" "three" "four" );
unset array[`shuf -i 0-4 -n1`]; 
echo ${#array[@]}
```

The problem I have, is that If I repeat that test, it normally will result in `3` ( the number of elements in the array), however repeat the exact same thing several times (usually less than 20) and it will result in `4`.
Update:  When this happens, it doesn't actually remove anything.

If I use:

```
v=${array[`shuf -i 0-4 -n1`]}
echo $v
array=( ${array[@]/$v/} )
echo ${#array[@]}
```

I get the exact same problem.  Sometimes the array is gone entirely, and `${#array[@]}` returns `3` and there is nothing where the element was.  Rarely however it returns `4` and the value is empty.  The test `echo $v` sometimes returns a null value, usually it works as expected and returns a number.  Here is where the problem is but I can't figure out why it is happening, but it is clearly why the # of elements doesn't change.

I do know the problem is with `shuf`.  If I just:

`unset array[2]  #specify, instead of using 'shuf' to randomize`

The element always goes away and the number of elements always reduces.
Further, questions about `shuf` generally involve its usage.

Is anyone familiar with this?  Am I misunderstanding a usage or is this a bug?  Any clue why `shuf` in particular would cause this problem?

As far as I can tell, `shuf` reliably returns a valid number, so it theoretically always returns a valid number to delete, and it does.  The behavior after that is random though and I've yet to figure out why it only matters when I use `shuf` to generate the array to go.  So, it seems as though I somehow get an unrecognized character or something when I pass it into a variable, and it could be null.

To test, I finally, I did a:

```
while [ true ]; do v=`shuf -i 0-4 -n1`; echo $v; done
```

for a while, I get a valid number.  So, it seems as though I somehow get an unrecognized character or something when I pass it into a variable.

Comment: I have tried this on more than one machine, including one I shelled into from work.  It doesn't appear to be a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have four array elements in your example.

```
array=( "one" "two" "three" "four" );
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four")'
```

Your `shuf -i 0-4 -n1` produce **five** different numbers (0,1,2,3,4).

Use

```
unset array[`shuf -i 0-3 -n1`]
```

or

```
unset array[$RANDOM%4]
```

Comment: You'd better use quotes: `unset 'array[$RANDOM%4]'`, otherwise your command is subject to pathname expansion. (And yes, these are single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh!  Thanks for the help, you beat me to my own answer.
I slept on it and my pretty (now) clear error finally dawned on me.

See, I'm writing a simple card game in bash (don't ask the details just go with me) and forgot to account for the 0-indexer ${deck[51]}.  When I intuitively shuffle 1-52... there's the problem right there.

Or as I did above for the example (and you all pointed out ;) ) my array was 4 elements, I was searching for 5.

Adding:

`exec 2> /tmp/45s.log
exec 1>&2
set -x`

At the beginning of my script helped me finally notice my error.  Thanks everyone for helping.  I situation where walking away for a while would've helped me.